# Drush 9 colors does not work

Tags: 8, drush

I have the following Drush command:

```
  /**
   * @command mycommand
   */
  public function myCommand() {
    $this->io()->success('MY TEST');
  }
```

**If I type in CLI:**

`drush mycommand` -> Formatted, but no colors

`drush mycommand --ansi` -> Formatted AND colors

Why does not colorize it in the first place?
Running composer for example uses color without an issue.

**My system**

- UBUNTU 16.0 server VM (through PUTTY terminal)
- Drush 9.5.2
- Drupal 8.6.2
- PHP 7.2

Comment: Both Composer and Drush uses Symfony Console AFAIK. Since you get colors by  default in Composer, I don't understand what is going on. Maybe better to post it as a bug report?

Comment: Most probably yes, I thought it something common. Btw also my colleagues have the same issue.

Comment: I'm having this issue as well on a pretty fresh system. Ubuntu 18.04. I downloaded `drush.phar` for drush 8.3.2 and placed it in `/usr/local/bin`.  `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`.  composer has colored output.  The Drupal site is 8.8.1, but I don't think it's relevant since I'm running a system level .phar.